# Javascript or Jquery update div in new opened child window - need syntax to update child window div

Tags: javascript, jquery, childwindow

I have an Ajax function that returns an html string as vReportContent.

Then I open a new html page using javascript window.open

There is a div on this page called 'divReportContent' that I want to update with vReportContent

Here's the javascript/jquery code example:

```
var vReportContent = msg; (returned from Jquery Ajax call - this works fine)
var vUrl = 'PrintReport.html';
var vWindowName = 'PrintReport';
window.open('' + vUrl + '', '' + vWindowName + '', width=1010, height=750;
```

***** Update the child (opened) window div with vReportContent

something like:
    $('#divReportContent').html(vReportContent);

Or a javascript equivalent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. We have to wait until the `document` inside the new `window` is loaded before we try to find the element.

```
var vReportContent = msg; (returned from Jquery Ajax call - this works fine)
var vUrl = 'PrintReport.html';
var vWindowName = 'PrintReport';
var newWindow = window.open('' + vUrl + '', '' + vWindowName + '', width=1010, height=750;

$(newWindow).load(function(){
   $(newWindow).find('#divReportContent').html(vReportContent);
});
```

Comment: This also does not work - I could put a div on the calling page and then use an opener method to access the parent div - but that seems redundant

Comment: Is the load handler being called?

Comment: Yes - I can trigger an alert  $(document).ready(function () {
                 alert('x');
             });

Comment: Please check my edited answer and check if you can see that alert.

Comment: I could use a function to call a hidden div on the parent form - but a report could be a sizeable content variable - so sticking in a hidden control on the calling form, then retrieving it from the called form seems bad practice. - the idea of waiting for the dom to be ready on the called for seems ok - as this would take not time - there's just one empty div. The issue is how to address that div from the calling form - thanks!

Comment: Yes - the alert 'window loaded' happens

Comment: It was indeed a combination of the two techniques!

Comment: @Charles - Can you accept this answer? So that next time people will answer you quickly like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var w = window.open(...);
$(w.document).find('#divReportContent').html(vReportContent);
```

Comment: This will not work because you are trying to find the element immediately after the window is opened which will definitely fail in most of the browsers and also if the network is slow.